# Xamarin Forms Reference Error for BitmapImage

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin.Forms Android project I'm getting the following error.

**Can not resolve reference: `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract`**,

Here is the code that is causing the error.`

```
 public class TemplateData
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage ImageData { get; set; }
}
```

The error occurs with the Android project,and occurs if I include the "BitmapImage" type. My UWP project compiles and runs with no errors.
I cannot find the reference NuGet package when I check with NuGet.

Comment: `BitmapImage` is not available in Android or iOS

Comment: if you need a cross platform Image framework, use SkiaSharp

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Bitmap` instead of `BitmapImage`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ImageSource` instead.

```
 public class TemplateData
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ImageSource ImageData { get; set; }
}
```